# Changing absolute URI to relative in HTTP POST header

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I have the following `POST` request:

```
POST http://blah/Request HTTP/1.1
Host: blah
Content-Length: 322
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Envelope>
<Header>
<UserID>uid</UserID>
<Password>pass</Password>
<SessionID />
<RequestType>GetDetails</RequestType>
<POSCompany>01</POSCompany>
<PackageType>DATA</PackageType>
<ActionType>READ</ActionType>
<SnoopUserID />
</Header>
<Body>
<MagicNumber>124</MagicNumber>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is failing with the error - (405) Method not supported

An example XML which apparently works on the server is the same but the header has the line `POST /Request HTTP/1.1` instead of `POST http://blah/Request HTTP/1.1`.

I don't know if this is the problem but I am trying to eliminate all possibilites. However, I cannot get the `POST` request URI to be relative and not absolute. Is there a wat to do this?

The following is the code used for sending the XML.

```
Public Sub SendXML(ByVal file As String)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(file)
    Dim data As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://blah/Request")
    request.Method = "POST"

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

    Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length

    Dim oStreamOut As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    oStreamOut.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    oStreamOut.Close()

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

End Sub
```

Asked here in response to a request at [405 - Method Not Allowed HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977894/405-method-not-allowed-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)

> 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to
>   introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs
>   allow the POST method necessary to process the form.
>
> All 405 errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and
>   security governing access to the content of the Web site, so should
>   easily be explained by your ISP.

Comment: As I say above, I have been provided with a file that does work and _apparently_ the third party server does accept POST requests.

Comment: Marked as answer as we had been given the wrong IP for the server, it was one that was setup to accept `POST` requests from our parent company rather than ourselves. Numerous times they confirmed we were using the correct IP until eventually they realised it was wrong.